# Howe to delete table rows with text content

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to delete each table row where td has class=feldtyp1 and the text content is `<p>News</p>`.

I am already come so far that the whole row is deleted.
Now I still need the query whether the cell with the class feldtyp1 containing textual content News

Could someone help me?

**Part of my source XML**

```
<table class="feldtyp">
   <tr>
      <td class="feldtyp1"><p>Feldtyp</p></td>
      <td class="feldtyp2"><p>Text</p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="feldtyp1"><p>News</p></td>
      <td class="feldtyp2"><p>Text</p></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**My current XLS deletes all rows**

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tr|td[@class='feldtyp1']"/>
    <xsl:template match="tr|td[@class='feldtyp2']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The desired result should look like this**

```
<table class="feldtyp">
   <tr>
      <td class="feldtyp1"><p>Feldtyp</p></td>
      <td class="feldtyp2"><p>Text</p></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to delete each table row where td has class=feldtyp1 and the
>   text content is `<p>News</p>`.

That's not entirely clear. Assuming you want to delete any row that contains a cell whose class is "feldtyp1" and it (the *same* cell) has a `<p>News</p>` child element, you should do:

```
<xsl:template match="tr[td[@class='feldtyp1'and p[.='News']]]"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.